# JNDI lookup fails for deployed EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I wrote a EJB module, and I deployed it to GlassFish. Then, I wrote an entreprise application client, and deployed that too to GlassFish.

The stateless bean's code:

```
package remote;

@Stateless
@Remote(IPersonEJB.class)
@LocalBean
public class PersonEJB implements IPersonEJB{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "JobsPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public Person giveJobToPerson(Job job, Person person) {
    em.persist(person);
    em.flush();
    job.setEmployeeID(person.getId());
    em.persist(job);
    return person;
}

// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
// "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

@Override
public Person getPerson(Long id) {
    return em.find(Person.class, id);
}
}
```

Persistence.xml of the deployed EBJ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="JobsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__TimerPool</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I imported the project as a library into the client's project (through Netbeans) in order to use the classes I needed:

```
package jobsclient;

import Entities.Address;
import Entities.Job;
import Entities.Person;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import remote.IPersonEJB;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        IPersonEJB personEJB = (IPersonEJB) ctx.lookup("java:global/Jobs/IPersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB");
        Address add = new Address("Fake street", "Fake city", "FC", "83100");
        Person p = new Person("Jack", "Black", add);
        Job j = new Job("Programmer", 3500f);

        Person persistente = personEJB.giveJobToPerson(j, p);
        if (persistente.getId() != null) {
            System.out.println("Creazione effettuata");
        }    }

}
```

If I try to run the client I get these exceptions:

```
Warning: C:\Users\Paolo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JobsClient\dist\gfdeploy\JobsClient does not exist.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/Jobs/IPersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: IPersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at jobsclient.Main.main(Main.java:28)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: IPersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Java Result: 1
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

I tried to find a solution, I read some other questions like this one here on Stackoverflow, but I could not solve my problem. I suppose it's a problem with the JNDI name? But I can't find the name it was deployed with anywhere (I look everywhere in the glassfish admin console) and I think the formatting of the name string is right (going by the guides I read).

I deployed both applications using netbeans' deploy function. Maybe I'm missing some configuration files (ejb.xml or other)?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the error: I was looking up the remote interface and not the bean itself.

```
    IPersonEJB personEJB = (IPersonEJB) ctx.lookup("java:global/Jobs/IPersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB");
```

Should be

```
    IPersonEJB personEJB = (IPersonEJB) ctx.lookup("java:global/Jobs/PersonEJB!remote.IPersonEJB");
```